# How to test Zend framework2 form which implements CSRF element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have created the login form using **Zend/Form** and it contains input elements as well as CSRF element.

```
<!-- sample login.phtml code snippet -->
<form method="post" action="/xyz">
<?php
 echo $this->formelement($form->get('email'));
 echo $this->formelement($form->get('password'));
 echo $this->formelement($form->get('csrf'));
 echo $this->formelement($form->get('submit'));
?>
</form>
```

The following testcase fails because of the validation against CSRF element.

```
public function testLogin()
{      
  //code goes here
  $params = array('email' => 'example@test.com', 'password' => 'example@test.com');
  $this->dispatch($url, $method, $params);
  //if the given username and password is correct the login page redirected to default home page
  $this->assertResponseStatusCode(302);
}
```

In the above testcase i set the email and password values but i don't know how to set CSRF element. How could i test the form which implements CSRF element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with the following:

```
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $csrf = $form->get('csrf')->getValue();
    $params = array('email' => 'example@test.com', 
                    'password' => 'example@test.com', 
                    'csrf' => $csrf
    );
```

Unless your form needs the form manager when you are going to have to use that rather than just instantiating the class but that's pretty easy to do in a unit test as well.

UPDATE:

Another method that works:

```
    $form = new LoginForm();
    $form->prepare();

    $params = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters(
                    array(
                            'csrf' => $_SESSION['Zend_Validator_Csrf_salt_csrf']['hash'],
                            'yourotherparams' => 'thingsandstuff'
            );


    $this->dispatch($url, $method, $params);
```

Comment: How could i reuse the instantiated form while dispatching the specified URL?

Comment: Pretty sure the csrf token will just get added to SessionContainer when you do this and will be available in SessionContainer when you dispatch to url

Comment: test case is still fails! may i know the reason for failure?

Comment: both `$_SESSION['Zend_Validator_Csrf_salt_csrf']['hash']` and `$form->get('csrf')->getValue();` returns the same hash key.

Comment: I figured that would be the case but then the $_SESSION method is actually how I do it in unit tests which works fine so thought I would add that too. My tests don't use the class you are using though which I assume is AbstractControllerTestCase

Comment: What does $form->getMessages return if you var dump out in your controller after isValid call?

Comment: you are correct i am using AbstractControllerTestCase because i found the example from [ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#your-first-controller-test). how could you write test case against CSRF element without using AbstractControllerTestCase?

Comment: Using a custom made Controller Test Class which is somewhat similar to AbstractControllerTestCase. Prior to zf2 2.1 AbstractControllerTestCase was not in existence. Can't really see why it wouldn't work though just saying I have no experience of using that class with this method of testing forms sadly

Comment: I am new to PHP as well as ZF2. Everyday i face a new problem furthermore i don't get proper tutorial to start learning. Thanks for your replies. if possible can you help me how to write custom testcases?

Comment: Your solution is absolutely perfect! `echo var_dump($loginForm->getMessages());` returns empty array when i set CSRF by using your logic.